# KDE plasma startup time on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, services

Thanks for stopping by to read this and many thanks in advance.
Im running Plasma KDE as an second DE on Xubuntu 18.04.The laptop is an old one with relatively good specs and the root partition is on an SSD.4gb ram , dual core intel T2080,kernel 5.3.6.Im stuck at understanding the delay between systemd timesync service and rendering of kuiserver.
Below is the snippet from journalctl -b but before that ::

Where is the 9 secs going when systemd-timesyncd reports its done syncing time at 04 17:14:36 and then for 9 secs nothing seems to happen till at 17:14:45 the kuiserver reports that its starting the service.Is the system just idling or is there anything else i can do to find out whats happening?

systemd-analyze blame for timesync service is 196ms so the time sync service i think is ok.

```
196ms systemd-timesyncd.service

Apr 04 17:14:36 ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[466]: Synchronized to time server [2001:67c:1560:8003::c8]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).


Apr 04 17:14:45 ubuntu dbus-daemon[950]: [session uid=1000 pid=950] Activating service name='org.kde.kuiserver' requested by ':1.23' (uid=1000 pid=1289 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell ")


Apr 04 17:14:45 ubuntu dbus-daemon[950]: [session uid=1000 pid=950] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.kuiserver'
```

Comment: Did the boot time actually seem to stop for those 9 seconds there?  If not, that could be your system was 9 seconds slow at the time of the timesync that happened and adjusted your time accordingly.

Comment: Hi,the the machine was booting.That 9 seconds is added to the total time taken for complete rendering of the kde desktop from greeter till the desktop is rendered and ready to use. There is some more from journalctl _PID=1 , 23:37:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
 23:37:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
23:46:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service. Between systemd tmp file service started and network manager starting not sure what the system is doing for 10 secs.thanks